# Is there a way to set files as Jinja-HTML automatically?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jinja2

I just recently started working with flask and jinja.  I installed Better Jinja for templating and it works fine after I set the Language Mode to Jinja HTML, but it's annoying to have to change that setting every time.  Is there a way to make that the default (not sure if there's a problem with having files with Jinja set to Jinja HTML) or to have it change automatically when I enter that code?

Answer (score 0):

use the setting

```
  "files.associations": {
    "*.html": "jinja"
  }
```

You can change this setting on workspace level.